# What is the most pyhthonic way of printing instance variables?

Tags: python

I have a node object that has x and y variables. I keep all of the nodes in a list called nodelist. What is the most pythonic and simple way of printing coordinates of all nodes from nodelist?

More specifically, I have a class called someclass that has

```
someclass.state
someclass.nodelist
```

I want to print its state and coordinates of the nodes in nodelist in as few as possible lines.

something like: `print self.state, (i.x, i.y for i in self.nodelist)`

Comment: implement `__str__` or `__unicode__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pythonic way to print is to use `print` and the pythonic way to represent an object as a string (what would be printed) is to define `__str__` (note that `__unicode__` is gone in python3 and is maybe not that pythonic any longer, especially when `__str__` will do (ie no unicode support is needed)). Note also that the new way of formatting string is with `str.format` rather than using the percent operator - so I use that.

In whatever class `self` is of:

```
def __str__(self):
     return "{0} {1}".format(self.state, (str(i) for i in self.nodelist))
```

and in whatever class `self.nodelist` elements are in:

```
def __str__(self):
     return "{0}, {1}".format(self.x, self.y)
```

and then just print the the objects using `print(obj)`

Comment: Thank you, this is going to be very useful.